# how i can make value range for weight in keras?

Tags: python, keras

I am a beginner learning in Deep learning framework with keras backend tensorflow and start learning with this  [sample code](https://machinelearningmastery.com/handwritten-digit-recognition-using-convolutional-neural-networks-python-keras/) https://machinelearningmastery.com/handwritten-digit-recognition-using-convolutional-neural-networks-python-keras/.

I want to make boundaries for my weight in keras model. I want to make my weights value in the range from -1 to 1. How can i do that?

I read about weight decay, weight constraint, weight clipping, making condition boundaries in file keras optimize.py ,  but because my lack of experience i can't decided which should i use.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. My reason is i am researching with custom sigmoid activation function and i want to modify my weight too

Comment: try this link , it may help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54435998/keras-limiting-output-min-max-value

Comment: @RishiBansal Thank you for your response, i will try it